# scapy ICMP show ( ttl ) only

Tags: python, networking, scapy, ttl

I am trying to send a icmp packet to a machine in my network but I need to show the ttl only

the command that I used : `q = sr1(IP(dst="192.168.1.8")/ICMP())`

Then I run : `q.show2()`

Output :

```
###[ IP ]### 
  version= 4
  ihl= 5
  tos= 0x0
  len= 28
  id= 8236
  flags= 
  frag= 0
  ttl= 128
  proto= icmp
  chksum= 0x9757
  src= 192.168.1.8
  dst= 192.168.1.5
  \options\
###[ ICMP ]### 
     type= echo-reply
     code= 0
     chksum= 0xffff
     id= 0x0
     seq= 0x0
```

How to show only the ttl !!

Comment: `print(re.search('ttl.*',q.show2()).group())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use, if you want some advanced formatting:

```
q.sprintf("%IP.ttl%")
```

Demo:

```
a = IP()
a.sprintf("%IP.ttl%")
'64'
```

But you could also just get the attribute:

```
a = IP()
ttl = a[IP].ttl
```